# Frame not getting opened

Tags: java, swing

package gc;

```
import static gc.Login.pass;
import static gc.Login.uname;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

public final class Mymain extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public static String name = "";
public  String msg;

XMPPConnection connection;
public Mymain() throws NullPointerException,IOException,XMPPException {
initComponents();
welcome.setText(name);

}


public Mymain(String username,String password) throws    IOException,XMPPException,NullPointerException, InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com",5222, "gmail.com");
connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
connection.login(username,password);
name = username;
Mymain setter = new Mymain();

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
try {
new Mymain().setVisible(true);
} catch (NullPointerException | IOException | XMPPException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Mymain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
}); 

begin_chat(); 
}
public void begin_chat() throws IOException, XMPPException,NullPointerException {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

 Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat("rssrivandla@gmail.com", new MessageListener() {

 @Override
 public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message msg) {
 if(msg.getType() == Message.Type.chat)
 if (msg != null && msg.getBody() != null)
 System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() + " says: "
                            + (msg != null ? msg.getBody() : "NULL"));
 }
 });
 while((msg = br.readLine())!=null) {

 chat.sendMessage(msg);
 }
 if(msg.equals("bye"))
 {
 connection.disconnect();
 }
 }



 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
 private void initComponents() {

 jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
 jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
 jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
 welcome = new javax.swing.JLabel();
 jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
 jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

 jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

 setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 setTitle("Ch@t Me!");
 setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
 setResizable(false);

 jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 204));

 jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
 jLabel1.setText("Heya,");

 welcome.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 1, 18)); // NOI18N

 jSeparator1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
 jSeparator1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

 jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
 jLabel3.setText("Buddies Online");

 javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
 jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
 jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
 jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jSeparator1)
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 61, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(welcome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 389, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(67, 67, 67))))
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(57, 57, 57)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(398, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(welcome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(293, 293, 293))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,             layout.createSequentialGroup()  
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void main(String args[]) {

}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
public static javax.swing.JLabel welcome;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

why the frame is not getting opened even though initComponents() is called? when i remove begin_chat() from parameterised constructor, frame is getting displayed... i need the frame to be displayed along with the begin_chat function working ... so, anyone pls help me..

Answer (score 1):

> when i remove begin_chat() from parameterised constructor, frame is getting displayed...

Sounds like your chatting code is blocking the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You need this code to execute in a separate Thread so the GUI is free to repaint itself and respond to user events.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. You would probably use a SwingWorker to handle the chatting code.

Comment: thanx for the help.. but even when i use swingworker its not working ... any further help pls?